# Is Html5 Webkit filesystem API persistent .txt file permanent, even if the user clears all cookies

Tags: html, cookies, webkit, fileapi, html5-filesystem

I'm working on a html5 web app which stores json data to .txt using webkit (ref code below). but once i cleared the cookies and cache the .txt file is destroyed in chrome browser. i followed the tutorial from http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html

is the filesystem api destroyed on cleaning cookies and cache ?

is there any other way i can look into to store json data in .txt file in user system ?

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT , 1024*1024, SaveDatFileBro);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance